# How can I reference a project as a package dependency with a specific version in AppVeyor and GitVersion?

Tags: nuget, appveyor, nuget-spec, gitversion

I have following `after_build` definitions in my `appveyor.yml`:

```
after_build:
- cmd: nuget pack "%project_file%" -properties "Configuration=%configuration%" -version "%GitVersion_NuGetVersion%" -symbols
- cmd: nuget pack "%extras_project_file%" -properties "Configuration=%configuration%" -version "%GitVersion_NuGetVersion%" -symbols
```

Now, I have those two `.proj`-files, which contain a corresponding `.nuspec`-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Finally, I have a little addition for the `extras_project_file`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="***project_name***" version="$version$" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

> Actually, ***project_name*** is replaced with a hardcoded value for simplicity reasons - no injection with `-properties` yet. Secondly, any project related elements, such as `description` and `authors`, have been omitted to provide a neutral question, despite being mandatory for the actual packing.

`project_file` is packed succesfully:

> Attempting to build package from 'Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Controller.csproj'.
>   MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
>   Packing files from 'C:\projects\dotnet-caliburn-micro-contrib-controller\src\Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Controller\bin\Release'.
>   Using 'Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Controller.nuspec' for metadata.
>   Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies
>   Successfully created package 'C:\projects\dotnet-caliburn-micro-contrib-controller\Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Controller.0.1.0-unstable0068.nupkg'.

Whereas `extras_project_file` fails:

> Attempting to build package from 'Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Controller.Extras.csproj'.
>   MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
>   Packing files from 'C:\projects\dotnet-caliburn-micro-contrib-controller\src\Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Controller.Extras\bin\Release'.
>   Using 'Caliburn.Micro.Contrib.Controller.Extras.nuspec' for metadata.
>   Found packages.config. Using packages listed as dependencies
>   **Versions using SemVer 2.0.0 are not supported: 0.1.0-unstable.68+Branch.develop.Sha.7f85e35f315f7fe3ecd35762b65802e5467a57c2.**

I am not even sure that this feature (token replacement in `<dependencies>`) is actually available.

If not, how else can I package two `.csproj`-files into two separate `.nupkg`-files, where one has a dependency on the other one with a specific version (same version as the package to build)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way for this scenario - but it misses `%AssemblyInformationalVersion%` being stamped into the final `.dll`-file as an attribute (so I'll need to inspect the `GitVersionInformation`-class for the actual value).

I added `assembly-informational-format: '{LegacySemVerPadded}'` to `GitVersion.yml`.

Next, I removed the additional `dependencies`-element in `.nuspec`, so both match again (=reset).

Finally, I adapted my `after_build`:

```
after_build:
  cmd: nuget pack "%project_file%" -properties "Configuration=%configuration%" -symbols 
  cmd: nuget pack "%extras_project_file%" -properties "Configuration=%configuration%" -IncludeReferencedProjects -symbols
```